# User Login Authentication using forms and Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, authentication, django-forms

I am trying to set up the user authentication for the login page using forms and comparing it to database values and my code works but then I realized I was getting login successful if I put any password if it was available in the database. What I want to do is to search for the mail and get the password for that user only not the whole database. My database will contain no duplicate emails so I don't have to worry about that. I have spend too much time trying to figure out how to get the password for same user the email is.

my login.views look like this

```
def login(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = Studentlogin(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = User.objects.create_user(email, password)
        try:
            studentemail = students.objects.get(email=email)
            studentpass = students.objects.get(password=password)
            return render (request, 'subscrap/main.html', {'student': studentemail })
        except:
            messages.success(request, 'Error, either Email or Password is not correct')
            pass
else:
    form = Studentlogin()
return render(request, 'subscrap/login.html', {'form': form})
```

My student model looks like this:

```
class students(models.Model):
fname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
lname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
password = models.CharField(max_length = 50 , null = True)
passwordrepeat = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=150)
class Meta:
    db_table = "students"
```

My form file:

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = students
        fields = "__all__"

class Studentlogin(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=150)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length = 50, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make only one query to get the student with the given email and password:

```py
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Studentlogin(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = User.objects.create_user(email, password)
            try:
               student = students.objects.get(email=email, password=password)
               return render (request, 'subscrap/main.html', {'student': student})
            except:
               messages.success(request, 'Error, either Email or Password is not correct')
        else:
           form = Studentlogin()
        return render(request, 'subscrap/login.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query set on the students model `students.objects.get(email=email)` returns a SINGLE student OBJECT where their email is equal to the email retrieved from the form. A more accurate variable name would be `student`. Note `.get()` returns a `DoesNotExist` error if there isn't a matching record.

From what you have you can then do (not ideal)

```
try
    student = students.objects.get(email=email)
    if student.password == password:
        return render (request, 'subscrap/main.html', {'student': email})  # (or student.email)
    else:
        raise Exception()
except:
    messages.success(request, 'Error, either Email or Password is not correct')
```

Building on what RedWheelbarrow wrote. Their query set looks for a student based on who had both the exact `email` and `password`. The query set still returns a single student though so if you just want to return the email in your render you need to do

```
try:
    student = students.objects.get(email=email, password=password)
    return render (request, 'subscrap/main.html', {'student': email})  # (or student.email)
except:
    messages.success(request, 'Error, either Email or Password is not correct')
```

Read more on qeueryset `get` method [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#get)